# UnreachableBrowserException after a recent system update

Tags: selenium, webdriver

My scripts were running fine till my system got an update through the network.

After the system update (Note: Internet Explorer updates are turned off from the help menu), the Internet Explorer loads and the login page is displayed. However, after login, the subsequent steps are not executed. The system waits for a very long time (longer than the waits specified in the code) and throws an UnreachableBrowserException caused by SocketException.

This issue is observed for InternetExplorer 11 only. On Firefox, the script executes without any issues.

The Selenium version is 2.53 and the IEDriver version is 2.53.1 (64 bit). Tried with IEDriver version 32 bit as well but the issue remains.

Also note that I have made the configuration for IE11 according to the site:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

Comment: just a guess kindly please do a fresh re installation of the browser look if it works then

Comment: I have tried installing a fresh copy of IE11. However, after the re-install, the system update is re-triggered and the issue is observed again.